# Proof $ A \subseteq B \Rightarrow |B \setminus A| = |B| - |A| $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is my proof valid?

It's intended to be more of a combinatorial proof.

Let $ A, B $ be arbitrary finite sets such that $ A \subseteq B $. $ B \setminus A $ is the set of all the elements present in $ B $ that are not present in $ A $. Therefore, if $  \left|B\right| = m \land \left|A\right| = n $, then in  order to find $ \left|B\setminus A\right| $, we want to subtract all the elements of $ A $ from $ B $, and because there no elements of $ A $ outside of $ B $, then $ \left| B \setminus A \right| = \left|B\right| - \left|A \right| $.

Comment: hint: $(B\setminus A) \cup A= B$ is a disjoint union of $B$

Comment: Yeah, I know this proof, I just wanted to knlw if my proof is ok too

Comment: @C Squared the hint is fine. but you need to rephrase "is a disjoint union of $B$"